# Laravel - php artisan queue:work in windows

Tags: laravel, windows, queue, wamp, startup

I have launched my script in windows with `wamp server`. I send email with `queue` in Laravel and I created batch file and add to windows startup.
`mybatchfile` is

```
php artisan queue:work
```

It works correctly. My question is there any better way to run `php artisan queue:work` in windows?

Comment: Development or production? `pm2` (`npm install pm2 -g`) and `pm2 start myfile`

Comment: @S.Wasta production. what is the difference between them `windows startup` and `pm2`

Comment: I gave you a alternative for both scenario. If you have problems with `pm2` running batch, can give a try to `supervisord` (you have to install it and it's not as easy as pm2, not difficult either). I don't use `pm2` in production because I use nothing from node (node have a lot of default libraries...) and install it isnt worth...